# What's the most correct way of stopping my pages from caching?

Tags: cross-browser

Google is giving me mixed responses, so I am guessing it is highly browser subjective, but what would you recommend I put in (and also where) to stop pages caching?

Comment: To stop whose pages from caching?  To stop your browser from caching pages?  To stop other people's browsers from caching pages you put up?  (The last is not really possible, although you can request it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but when I used to do a lot of this, the advice was always to:

Set:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: max-age -1
```

Here's a [good article](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) about the various nuances.

Answer (score 0):

I've used:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache" 
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" 
Response.Expires = -1
```

or in ASP.NET, place this in your code behind (page or master page)

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
```